# How to do ajax in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need some help, I have a jquery ajax function and I would like to do it in PHP.

```
var accessToken = '237d48b642d5443495a9ec62811c97d7';
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + accessToken},
        data: JSON.stringify({query: 'hello u, sessionId: '1'}),
        success: function(data){
          setResponse(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
        }
      });
```

I would like to convert the above ajax to php and I have done this:

```
$accessToken = '237d48b642d5443495a9ec62811c97d7';
$url = 'https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910';
$data = ['query'=>'stupid', 'sessionId'=>'123'];
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data),
    'header'=>  ["Authorization" => "Bearer" . $accessToken "\r\n"] .
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );
```

But I'm getting an error and do not know how to solve it.

Please help.

Comment: post your error traceback.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your js

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({query: 'hello u, sessionId: '1'}),` close the quotes properly

Comment: Try php  cURL to achieve this

Comment: Syntax highlighting editors are great for spotting errors, stop using notepad.

Comment: Also got a syntax error in PHP `.` at the end of `'header'`. Plus it should be an array not Array.string

Comment: alright got that. but now the ajax is working but the php is still not working. how do i make the php version work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS

```
var accessToken = '237d48b642d5443495a9ec62811c97d7';
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + accessToken},
  data: JSON.stringify({query: 'hello u', sessionId: '1'}),
  success: function(data){
    setResponse(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
  }
});
```

PHP

```
$accessToken = '237d48b642d5443495a9ec62811c97d7';
$url = 'https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910';
$data = array('query'=>"hello u", 'sessionId'=>1,'lang'=>'en');
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data),
    'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken. "\r\n" .
              "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );
```

Comment: Fixed a few errors in your code, let me know if it works.

Comment: i m getting this error     what does it mean 

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test1/index.php on line 15

Comment: Fixed it, Authorization was missing Bearer

Comment: alright dude. its working. thanks a lot for the help man. appreciate it a lot man

Comment: No problem, when you get the chance, please select the answer as the right one if it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try switching to PHP CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.api.ai/api/query?v=20150910');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$data = array('query'=>'stupid', 'sessionId'=>'123');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            http_build_query($data));

$accessToken = '237d48b642d5443495a9ec62811c97d7';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer'.$accessToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            ));         

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

$response = json_decode( $server_output );

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: i m getting this error stdClass Object ( [id] => 2bb036be-05e0-49c2-953b-dcd5200d2326 [timestamp] => 2017-09-27T03:27:21.119Z [lang] => en [status] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 400 [errorType] => bad_request [errorDetails] => Cannot parse json. Please validate your json. ) )